# Submitting form from Jquery Mobile Pop-up

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, razor, popup

I am writing a web app for iPad using Jquery Mobile and ASP.NET MVC4.

I have a form in one of my views that looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClose", "WO", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CloseForm" })) {
  <input type="hidden" name="idNumber" value="@Model.idNumber">              
  <a href="#popupCloseDialog" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" style="width:96%; margin-top: 4px">Close</a>
}
```

The <`a href>` in the above form calls a pop-up dialog in that same view that looks like this:

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="popupCloseDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false"
    style="max-width:416px;" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top" >       
            <h1 class="ui-title" style="width:80%; margin-left:40px">Confirm</h1>        
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">      
            <h3 class="ui-title" style="text-align:center; height:22px;">Are you sure you want to close Order # @Model.idNumber?</h3>
            <br />                                             
            <a id="popupCloseSubmit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back"
            data-mini="true" data-theme="b" style="width:175px;" type="button">OK</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" 
                data-mini="true" data-transition="flow" style="width:175px; margin-left:10px" data-theme="b" >Cancel</a>                 
        </div>                   
</div>
```

Note that this pop-up is outside of the "CloseForm".

I have simple jquery to submit "CloseForm" when a button inside the pop-up is clicked.  Here it is:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
 $("#popupCloseSubmit").on("tap", pwHandler);
   function pwHandler(event) {
     try {
       $("#CloseForm").submit();
     }
     catch (e) {
       alert(e.Message);
     }
   }
});
```

Now, this works most of the time.  The Dialog is called when the Close button in the form is clicked.  Once the "popCloseSubmit" button is clicked inside the pop-up, CloseForm is submitted and code proceeds to the "UpdateClose" Action in the "WO" Controller.  However, sometimes this process hangs up and the site just hangs there and does nothing.  I've put event logging in my Controller Action and in my database, so I can confirm that when this "hang up" behavior occurs, the code is never advancing to the "UpdateClose" Action.

The inconsistency of this behavior is baffling to me.  There seems to be no rhyme or reason why this is happening when it does.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Is there another way I should be submitting a form from a jquery mobile pop-up?

Please note that I am only testing this on an iPad - because that's the only place we need to it to function.  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Do you have to click _close_ to submit the form? in other words, is there another button e.g. cancel, or the user has no choice but clicking _close_? If yes, try submitting form once popup is completely closed. `$("#popupCloseSubmit").on("popupafterclose", pwHandler)` I'm afraid it's caused by changes in URL when popup is active.

Comment: Another note, are you using _single page_ or _multi-page_ model? make sure that `pageinit` event doesn't _multiply_ `tap` listener on same button. `pageinit` will fire once per page before showing it for the first time.

Comment: @Omar In the pop-up (id=popupCloseDialog), there is a button labeled "OK" (id=popCloseSubmit) and a button labeled "Cancel".  Cancel just dismisses the pop-up with no submit, OK submits the form (id = CloseForm).  So, yes there is another button/option.  So, I would think popupafterclose is a no go.  Interesting insight though.  Any other way around this?

Comment: My bad `$("#popupCloseDialog").on("popupafterclose", pwHandler)`. I didn't go through popup HTML. Just noticed `data-rel="back"` added to both buttons, add `data-history="false"` to popup div. Ok `popupafterclose` no go, make sure `tap` event fires once.

Comment: @Omar Just saw your second comment.  I'm using a Layout page with a single page that has Header and Content sections.  Each MVC View (.cshtml files) basically represent a different Content section to the layout.

Comment: @Omar I will try adding data-history="false" and start testing.  The bad thing about this is, since it's inconsistent, testing a change can take a while.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49512/discussion-between-omar-and-user2163572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full credit for this answer goes to @Omar, who suggested the solution.  After much testing, I can say that this was the answer for me.

When the form submit would "hang up", it was because the form was trying to submit prior to the Jquery Mobile pop-up box closing.  As @Omar pointed out, the URL changes when the pop-up is open.

Therefore my solution for this was to force the pop-up to close prior to the form submission.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
 var srclicked;
 $("#popupCloseSubmit").on("tap", srsubHandler);

   function srsubHandler(event) {
       srclicked = true;
   }

   $("#popupCloseDialog").on("popupafterclose", pcHandler);

   function pcHandler(event) {
       if (srclicked) {
           $("#CloseForm").submit();
           srclicked = false;
        }
   }
});
```

So, the pop-up, #popupCloseDialog contains a submit button (#popCloseSubmit) and a cancel button. When the submit (#popupCloseSubmit) button is clicked, I flag a variable (srclicked) as true.  The "popupafterclose" event fires every time #popupCloseDialog closes.  So, when the pop-up closes, I check to see if the variable srclicked is true.  If it is, I close the form (#CloseForm) and set the variable back to false.

I hope this helps someone else.  Many, many thanks to @Omar for taking the time to talk this over with me in chat.